# access text of textbox1 in tabPage1 from tabPage2 in C# visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, textbox, tabpage

I am writing my code in Visual Studio 2013 , c# . I have a tabControl , it has 2 tabs. there is a textbox in tab 1 ! I want to copy its text to a label in tab2 !

how can I do this?

can it be like :

```
label1.text = tabPage1.TextBox1.text;
```

I know it cannot be coz there is no `TextBox1` when I write `tabPage1`.  !

any idea?

Comment: Could you post more of your code as an example?  What type is tabPage1?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. All controls of a TabPage are local to a Form and accessible from the Form without adding any additional functionality. so only this line will work:

Label1.text = TextBox1.Text;

thank you all

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing the label directly, why don't you think you can do the same with your textbox?

```
label1.Text = textBox1.Text;
```